# Batch print files in alphabetical order

Tags: windows-xp, pdf, batch

I have a folder with hundreds of small PDF files to print.
How can I make a batch job to print them out in alphabetical order?

Answer (score 4):

Details [here](http://support.adobe.com/devsup/devsup.nsf/docs/52080.htm) about silent print command in Adobe reader.

so you can do (batch file):

```
for %%X in (*.pdf) do AcroRd32.exe /t %%X "\\servername\printername"
```

or (cmd prompt):

```
for %X in (*.pdf) do AcroRd32.exe /t %X "\\servername\printername"
```

Comment: Hi
this does not guarantee the print in alphabetical order. :(

Comment: Well, it does the same as a standard DOS dir *.pdf so it should be in order...

Comment: try this to prove the sort order:

for %X in (*.pdf) do echo %X

Comment: don't work... just try. 
I create files: 3.pdf, 1.pdf, 2.pdf in a folder. then your command:
C:\1>for %X in (*.pdf) do "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Acrobat 9.0\Acrobat\Acrobat.ex
e" /t %X

C:\1>"C:\Program Files\Adobe\Acrobat 9.0\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe" /t 1.pdf

C:\1>"C:\Program Files\Adobe\Acrobat 9.0\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe" /t 2.pdf

C:\1>"C:\Program Files\Adobe\Acrobat 9.0\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe" /t 3.pdf

but in the printer I found this order of printing: 2-1-3.
LOL! :)

Comment: that doesn't make sense!!! if the command is executed 1,2,3 then it should print 1,2,3...

Comment: I repeated same with the echo test, creating 2,1,3 and it has definitely echoed 1,2,3... (I'm on Win7)

Comment: Hi!
I know that is weird :(

Comment: what happens if you pause the print queue and send to print. What order do they appear in the queue?

Answer (score 4):

```
dir /b | sort > %temp%\files.tmp
for /f %f in (%temp%\files.tmp) do AcroRd32.exe /t %f "\\servername\printername"
del %temp%\files.tmp
```

Comment: thanks for your solution. anyway how come windows explorer sorts files   in a different order?

Comment: nobody knows why ?

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't stackoverflow, but the only way I could do this would be in python.

Recepie for printing pdf file:

```
from win32com import client
import time

ie = client.Dispatch("InternetExplorer.Application")

def printPDFDocument(filename):

    ie.Navigate(filename)

    if ie.Busy:
        time.sleep(1)

    ie.Document.printAll()
    time.sleep(2)

ie.Quit()
```

Recepie for list all files from a dir:

```
   import os
   path="C:\\somedirectory"  # insert the path to the directory of interest here
   dirList=os.listdir(path)
```

Recepie for sorting alfabetically the list of files:

```
a.sort()  # a is the list
```

Well just by joining the 3 recepies, you can have your problem solved.