# Print a series of PDF files

Tags: windows, pdf, printing

Is there a way to print several PDF files at once?  I have a bunch of individual files that I want to print (about 42).  Printing each one is tedious.  Does anyone know a way to print a whole series at once?  Maybe something like a PDF reader with a "Print All" function?

I ask because this isn't the first time I've run into this problem and have never been able to find a good solution...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Highlight them all (click on the first, hold `shift` while clicking on the last, or click on the first and then hold down `CTRL` while clicking on each file) in Windows explorer (may be not all unless you really trust your printer), right click and them click on print.

Windows may ask if you are sure, either be brave or try printing just a few at a time.

Comment: Ah.  This works in Windows 7 so long as you have 15 or less selected.  And a Google search turned up other people complaining about the same thing with no answer.  http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7files/thread/f712b72e-693c-4d32-ad4a-89c7c3a1fb47  This was the first thing I tried, but when I selected them all, I didn't get the option to print.

Comment: Well, that's progress for you. This seemed so bizarre that I went and checked it for myself. Obviously we users are just too stupid to make such difficult decisions for ourselves now; but I'd have thought that nowadays it wouldn't be such a problem anyway as machines have so much memory: if Microsoft wanted to remove the warning they'd have been better just letting the user open ridiculous numbers of files.

Answer (score 1):

[Batch print files in alphabetical order](https://superuser.com/questions/116467/batch-print-files-in-alphabetical-order)